# Three different dimensions shown in package drawing, what do they mean?

Tags: footprint, packages, drawing

I have an IC that uses this package from analog devices: https://www.analog.com/media/en/package-pcb-resources/package/pkg_pdf/lfcspcp/cp_8_5.pdf.
Most of the dimensions are shown in three numbers:

[image: dimensions]

I can't find any information on what this means, I suppose there is a max/min value, but then what the third one would mean and in what order they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indicating tolerance. From the top down

MAX, nominal, MIN